# ExtensionlessUrlHandler causes 404 Not Found with default document on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-handlers

I recently updated some ASP.NET Nuget packages and modified the `index.html` file of my web site. Now I get 404-Not Found error but ONLY for the root path, i.e. when the web site address is typed without subdirectory or file name.

If I explicitly append "/index.html" then the default document is displayed correctly.

I also noticed that the line below in my web.config file has an unexpected behavior: If I remove the line, then the root path can be displayed, but the Web API requests return 404-Not Found response. If I keep it, then Web API requests work but the default document causes 404-Not Found.

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

The complete "handlers" section of web.config is as follows:

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

I made no changes to the default document setting or physical path file permissions. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that the problem has nothing to do with my modification in index.html. The actual cause originated from the way MVC routing works: I had just added MVC components to my project, and newly-added MVC route config started digesting all extensionless paths. As per [this explanation](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/aug/15/iis-default-documents-vs-aspnet-mvc-routes), I just added an exception for the root path (the empty string), and the problem was fixed:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("");

        ...
    }
}
```